# How to hide focus ring for NSTextFieldCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm trying to get this blue border (which is around a NSTextFieldCell when you can edit the value) out of the way. Is there a way manage this somehow? At the same time the user should still be able to change the text just by double-clicking, though.

For the table itself I got rid of it by setting this **Focus ring** option to None. But I can't find it for any Text Field unfortunately...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't forget to check superclasses when looking in the docs for something. In this case, since `NSTextFieldCell` inherits from `NSCell`, you want to use [`-[NSCell setFocusRingType:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000074-BBCJHACC).

The easiest way to get the cell before it becomes focused is probably the [`NSTableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008622-CH1-SW12) method `tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
                  row:(NSInteger)row 
{        
    NSTextFieldCell * cell = [tableColumn dataCellForRow:row];
    [cell setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do I adapt this to the Table View? Since I don't have access to any of the `NSTextFieldCells`s directly, I have no idea where to call `setFocusRingType`.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to upload a screenshot, but I couldn't... However, it works now. Thank you very much!